# Writing to a text file at specific position?

Tags: c#

How to write a file in a specific position instead of giving space like `"           "`.Here i am writing to a file,the output i am getting is like

```
TIMESTAMP              'ATRS_ACCT_TIMESTAMP',
OU_ID              'ATRS_ACCT_OU_ID',
COMPANY_CODE              'ATRS_ACCT_COMPANY_CODE',
BU_ID              'ATRS_ACCT_BU_ID',
```

but i need output like this

```
TIMESTAMP          'ATRS_ACCT_TIMESTAMP',
OU_ID              'ATRS_ACCT_OU_ID',
COMPANY_CODE       'ATRS_ACCT_COMPANY_CODE',
BU_ID              'ATRS_ACCT_BU_ID',
```

Here is my code

```
string[] ss = new string[tblSchema.Rows.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < tblSchema.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ss[i] = (tblSchema.Rows[i]["ColumnName"].ToString());
    dest.WriteLine(ss[i].ToUpper() + "              " + 
                   "'" + textBox2.Text + ss[i].ToUpper() + "'" + ",");
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) and specify the field length for your fields.  Something like this:

```
var line = String.Format("{0,-20} '{1}{0}',", ss[i].ToUpper(), textBox2.Text);
// "{0,-20}" - Print the first item using a minimum of 20 characters left aligned
dest.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this helps for understanding:

```
    string txt = "Hello World";
    string txt2 = "Test";
    string txt3 = "Let's go";

    string line = String.Format("{0,-15} {1,-10} {2,10}", txt, txt2, txt3);

    Console.WriteLine(line);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

***Explanation:***

This will position the text between position 0-15 left aligned:

> {0,-15} = First string [txt], 1 = Text, -15 = amount of characters allowed for the string, - = left align

This will position the text between position 16-26 right aligned:

> {1, 10} = Second string [txt2], 1 = Text, 10 = amount of characters allowed for the string, right align

This will position the text between position 27-37 left aligned:

> {2, -10} = Third string [txt3], 2 = Text, -10 = amount of characters allowed for the string, - = left align

Answer (score 0):

You want to pad the strings before writing them. This will give the correct number of spaces. See this tutorial: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Language-Basics/Trimmingandpadding.htm

Answer (score 0):

use "\t" instead of " "- it inserts tabs instead of spaces.

EDIT:
my bad, didn't notice you were iterating over the table names.
It's hacky, but you can use a varying number of \t's based on the largest table name and the current table name...

Comment: This is only going to work if all of the table names finish within the same tab boundary.

Comment: I didn't notice he was using for loop over column name, otherwise I'd suggest simply using as many \t as needed...
It's ugly, but you can hack it using \t based on the largest table names relative to the current table name.